# jQuery selector based on child

Tags: jquery, selector

How would I, in the html below, select all divs where the closest child is not a span?

```
<div>test</div> //should be selected
<div>test2</div> //should be selected
<div><span>test2<span/></div> //should not be selected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo class selectors like [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```js
$("div:not(:has(span))").css("color","red");
```

```html
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div>test</div> 
<div>test2</div> 
<div><span>test2</span></div>
```

---

If you only want to ignore if the first child node is span then use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```js
$("div").filter(function() {
  // get all children nodes and check first node is span(assuming there isn't any comment node)
  return !$(this).contents().first().is('span');
}).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div>test</div>
<div>test2</div>
<div><span>test2</span></div>
<div>test3<span>test2</span></div>
<div> <span>test2</span></div>
```